# Errors occurred while generating the coverage report

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

After the tests are completed, a code coverage generation error occurs

I get this error "Failed to generate coverage for target * Malformed instrumentation profile data"

I've got mixed (obj-c & swift) project.

[image: Error image]